# Auto restarting Ajax request after Javascript is turned off and then turned on

Tags: javascript, ajax, local-storage, polling

Is there any way to continue sending Ajax requests ( for example, in a polling application, where a request is sent whenever a response from the previous request is received, starting immediately on page load) when Javascript is turned on after it has been turned off by the user for some time?

And as for the value of variables, I have observed that the behavior is inconsistent: some browsers retain the value of the variables already set when Javascript is resumed, others don't. So if I want to save all the values during a particular tab session, would it be a good idea to save all variables (there can be like thousands of them in a complex script!) as local variables (through local storage API, or jStorage, which works in IE6 and IE7 as well) that will auto destroy when the tab is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ajax is depend on Javascript, It will not work when the turned off javascript support resumed in your browser without page reload by any mean.

From Ajax defination: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29
I think it is not possible.

Comment: Yep, I think so too, but in Facebook, if you turn off JS, you will find that the news ticker in the top right gets blurred, indicating that JS is turned off, so it can't fetch data by AJAX, so it might as well auto-disable. However once you enable JS, the blur is removed, and notifications start sliding in normally? How do they do it then? Do they use IFrame or something? This could be solved by `setTimeout`, which could check for the JS status periodically and remove the blur, but even that is disbaled when JS is disabled. And how can the blur action take place after JS is turned off?

Comment: Try to check this feature in a browser does not support HTML5, it will not act as you described. I think, Indeed I'm sure, the blur effect due to features of CSS3 and HTML5! There is no another probability!

Comment: But how can CSS3/HTML5 detect JS disabling?

Comment: Exactly I don't know,but In HTML4 we had <noscript> tag which is invoked when there is no Javascript support! I don't know much about CSS3 and HTML5 but from some code and effects that it do we may notice that its ability to add hover and some other effects to the document. Also don't forget the meta tag refresh which may able to load and reload styled iframe!<noscript><iframe></iframe></noscript> and every page of the iframe is refreshed and loading the another one in infinite loop manner. and when the iframe find Javascript turned on again it affects the opener window or reload it by ajax.

Comment: Yeah, I too guessed that they might be using Iframe, but Iframes often cause the tab title to show the reloading symbol, indicating that it is fetching another page, even though it is not refreshing the page. But in FB I never see this happen. How come?

Comment: Reload symbol is a just an animated gif image could be placed in an iframe set i.e iframe inside another iframe!
Don't forget that the alternative to ajax using iframe. I had written a PHP Captcha Class with loadable captcha image using iframe not ajax. It called fox_captcha on phpclasses.org

Comment: Oh, ok then. So is there any way to achieve what I mentioned in my question?

Comment: Yes there is but It depends on, as I regarded in my answer, on the ability of reloading the page.